# Better clarity on Monitor for Development

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, displayport

I have a Dell e6400 running Win7 32 bit with "Mobile Intel 4 series express chipset family" display adapter.
For work, I connect it to a Dell Monitor (SE198WFP) using DVI (Dual Link) cable between the two.

The display is ok - but I want to check if there's any way to improve it my reading/viewing experience (with a new screen, new connection or a new laptop)

I spend hours on the computer mainly doing server side software development - text readability is most important for my work, no graphical user interface or animation.

My question is - **How can I improve my setup, for a more crisp quality display?**

...like on iPad2 or the latest high quality TV (Imagine ESPN HD).
I love the clarity i see on HD Channels on the latest TVs and would like to have the same experience at work.

I'm willing to get whatever it takes - DisplayPort Laptop and Monitor or higher resolution display card etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external SE198WFP monitor has a resolution of 1440x900. This is low compared to the standard HD resolution (1920x1080) of most 20"+ monitors these days.

The simplest way to improve your display experience is to get a 20" monitor which has HD (1920x1080) resolution. If you get a larger sized monitor, say 24" at the same resolution, it may not appear as "crisp" if you sit at the same distance.

Comment: Thanks- Sounds like higher resolution gives better quality of the display.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get an ipad. It would be useless for you.

[Your laptop:](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-e6400/pd)

> Display
>   14.1" Premium, UltraSharp™ WXGA+ (1440x900) LED Display
>   14.1" Premium Electronic Privacy WXGA (1280x800) LED Display
>   14.1" Premium WXGA (1280x800) Display
>
> Ports:  IEEE - 1394, docking connector, USB 2.0 (x4), VGA, Display
>   Port, RJ-11 (optional), RJ-45, eSATA, USB PowerShare,
>   headphone/speaker out, mic

If your laptop had hdmi output you would be good, but you only have 14" display and neither your laptop nor monitor can output more than 1440x900. With hdmi output from a laptop you could get 1920x1080 with any hdmi capable monitor/tv even if the laptop display did not support HD (I do this with my own HP laptop).

So besides getting a new laptop, a cheaper solution would be an older crt monitor (big & bulky but basically free now a days). The image displayed would be sharper and crisp, but you would not get HD resolution though.

New laptop otherwise, but make sure it has hdmi output. Then you can attach it to any hdmi television/monitor. Low end, high end, whatever size. Price of a ipad, you can get a new laptop with hdmi output. Then go wild on a really good monitor.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have an HDMI output on the laptop.  I mentioned iPad only as an example.  Thanks for the helpful response.